# Adding new elements to list R

Tags: r, list, nested

I'm having trouble updating a list. Say I create a list:

```
>list1 <- list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5),c(6,7,8))
list1
```

and I get:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 6 7 8
```

and I want to append an additional slice. So I try:

```
list2 <- list(list1,c(9,10,11))
list2
```

and I get:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 4 5

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 6 7 8


[[2]]
[1]  9 10 11
```

but what I really wanted was:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 6 7 8

[[4]]
[1]  9 10 11
```

If there's any solution that is computationally efficient, that would be great. This process is going to repeat over >800k slices.

I would also accept an alternative to using the list() function to create a nested data structure.

Comment: try `c(list1,list(c(9,10,11)))`

Comment: That worked perfectly.

Comment: @SamuelHaaf please accept Pierre answer then. We should not leave unresolved questions piling up even when the solutions worked for you.

Comment: these keeps piling up in the unanswered questions list and will grab unnecessary attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c(list1,list(c(9,10,11)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 6 7 8
# 
# [[4]]
# [1]  9 10 11
```

We can use `c` to concatenate the two lists.

Answer (score 1):

you should try `append`

```
append(list1,list(c(9,10,11)))
```

this gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 6 7 8

[[4]]
[1]  9 10 11
```

whereas

```
list(list1,c(9,10,11))
```

creates a new list and makes the previous `list1` and `c(9,10,11)` as its elements. Hence you are seeing new index [1] and [2].

Hope this helps